# core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: angular

In the console.log, I have an error message but I cannot solve this problem...

Here is the error message

```
core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

[image]

How should I declare `name` below?

```
 ...
    <ng-container *ngIf="dta && dta.PP">
 ...
```

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dta && dta.PP  ">
  <div class="card" style="width: 60%">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <td>{{ fiscalYear }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <td>{{ selectedCountry.name }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Register</th>
                <td>{{ registreNational }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
selectedCountry: Country;

ngOnInit(): void {
    ...

    this.service.getPaysDta().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe((countries) => {
        this.countries = countries;

        let selectedCountry = this.countries.find(c => c.id == this.country);
        if (selectedCountry) {
            this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
        }
    });

}
```

Country.ts

```
export class Country {
    id : string;
    name: string;

}
```

I don't know how to correctly declare the variable `name`... :S

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectedCountry` is undefined by default, it only gets assigned a value in the asynchronous `getPaysDta()` subscribe callback.

In the HTML you string interpolate `{{ selectedCountry.name }}`. Initially it will try to access the `name` property of `undefined`, hence the error message.

You can fix this very easily, by wrapping the string interpolation with an `*ngIf`.

Example:

```
<td>
<span *ngIf="selectedCountry">{{ selectedCountry.name }}</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan for your explanation. It works :-)